# Spike in Google Postmaster Tools Spam Rate Since Mid-October, Other Metrics Offer No Clues

Tags: sendgrid, spam, email-spam, google-postmaster

I work for mid-sized email sender, and we are very conservative when it comes to the mailing that we do. We only email users that opt-in to our service and we follow all best practices. Our user reported spam rate as reported in Google Postmaster Tools has been in the 0% to 0.2% for years.

Suddenly, on approximately 10/15/2020 our user-reported spam rate in Postmaster Tools jumped to 1.1%, then 1.9% a few days later, then 2.4% on both 11/01/2020 and 11/02/2020. In the days between and after these peaks it has still been high, averaging close to 1%.

Something seemed to happen on or around 10/15/2020 that we cannot account for.

Despite this, the rest of our metrics from SendGrid, the mailing platform we use, remain completely normal - our volume hasn't changed, our opens/unique open rate is the same it has always been, our click rates remain the same, and even our unsubscribe rate has not changed.

We haven't changed our templates or our content in over a year, we haven't introduced any new mailings, and our other feedback loops for other providers don't show this increase in spam rate.

Our domain and IP reputation in Postmaster Tools remains at "High", but this high spam rate that has continued daily for nearly a month now has us extremely worried and we aren't sure what to do about it.

Has anyone else ever experienced something like this, or have any advice on what we should do?

Comment: We experienced the same thing. It seems Goole Postmaster Tools had an update around  that time (as shown in the banner on its logged-in homepage). Some SocketLabs users did too, https://www.socketlabs.com/blog/google-postmaster-tools: `As of October 14th 2020 Google has changed the way it calculates this metric. Many good senders are seeing higher Spam Rates being reported by Google`

Comment: We're seeing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out in the comments, Google later announced that on October 14th of 2020 they had rolled out a change to the way that they calculated spam rates.